# What is the difference between OAuth user authentication and Active Directory user authentication?

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth-2.0, active-directory

I want that only the authenticated users can access my web application (.net).
For this, in my solution design I am proposing an Identity management system.

But I want to understand whether I should go with

> OAuth authentication
>
> or the Active Directory authentication
>
> What is the difference between these two and which one should used
>   when.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you´re mixing concepts:

`OAuth` is basically delegation of the authorization to another application. It can be an application written by you/your team, or it can be the active directory. Finally, it can be  the google login there is here in stackowerflow)

The authorization will generate a token and is the one used by the application to authorize each time.

What I think you are trying to compare is `SAML` with `OAuth`:

The main difference is what I told before, using OAuth you will trust the 3rd party application which the user is logged on.

SAML is an standard that achieves the Single sign on, federation and identity manager.

There is other differences

**The Token generated**

- `SAML` is an `XML
- `OAuth` is `Json`

**The transport layer**

- OAuth is limited to HTTP
- there is no limit for SAML

**The main goal**

- OAuth was fully designed to use into internet, to delegate the authorization to trusted companies.
- SAML was designed for enterprise scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it gave me an idea. I will research more on this.